# Smooth Embedding

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I need help showing that the following smooth map is not a smooth embedding: $f:\mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(z)= \operatorname{Re}(z)$.

I know that this map is not a submersion because the $dF$ vanishes at $0$, and I know it is not a covering map because it doesn't cover all of $\mathbb{R}$, just an interval of it.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It is _not_ an embedding. Since the derivative vanishes at two points, it is not even a submersion. (You cannot embed $S^1$ into $\mathbb{R}$ at all.)

Comment: I meant that it was not an embedding or a submersion. That is what I have written down. I am not sure how to prove it is NOT an embedding. I know if I can prove it is not an immersion, then it is not an embedding. But I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: If $f \colon S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then $f(S^1)$ is a connected compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$. That shows (how) that $f$ cannot be an immersion (hence not an embedding).

Answer (score 1):

The same reason that you gave for $f$ not being a submersion also tells you that $f$ is not an immersion (indeed, for maps between manifolds of the same dimension the concepts of immersion and submersion coincide). Any smooth embedding is in particular an immersion; and your map isn't.